# Visual Studio Community 'Ctrl+K,Ctrl+C' not available

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio Newb but trying to get used to it.

Right off the bat trying to comment out a few lines of a powershell script.

If I highlight the lines and then do a  'Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C', not letting go of Ctrl(But I did try it every which way).

I get the message -

> The key combination(Ctrl+K,Ctrl+C) is bound to command (Comment
> Selection) which is not currently available.

Or in the menu its greyed out.
[Comment Greyed Out in Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3zsg.png)

Haha, this just seems like such a standard thing to be able to do...I can't believe it has to be turned on somehow in Visual Studio.

I'd appreciate any advice on what I'm doing wrong... thank you!!

Comment: When you installed and ran VS for the first time it should have asked you what default settings you wanted. I know that the shortcut combo works for the Visual C++ Settings default; but I don't know what you picked.

Comment: Hey Casey... I don't get it... I created a quick helloworld.py and it let me use ctrl+k,c but if I just open a powershell script I can't use ctrl+k,c ???

Comment: Weird. No idea. I'm going to chock it up to: "Visual Studio really likes to work with solutions and projects, not individual files". Without a solution loaded, things break. I bet if you load that Python project into the IDE, then drag-and-drop your powershell script file into the text editor window it'll work.